# Find all positive integers s.t. $\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} - \frac{1}{d^2}$

Tags: number-theory

Find all positive integers $a, b, c, d$ such that :

$$\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} - \frac{1}{d^2}$$

The original problem came from atomic electron transitions :
[image: Bohr]

I would like to find out non-trivial positive integer solutions; since it is trivial if $a = b$ and $c = d$, or $a = c$ and $b = d$.

I found some of the solutions, and they look like :

[image: Solutions]

There is some pattern in these integers, but it seems difficult to obtain a gerneralized form of the solution.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1820011p12153836 on AoPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Remark:* The following is inspired by [Equation of 1/x^2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1820011p12153836) on AoPS. However, a bit more work is needed to characterize *all* solutions of the given equation. It does not suffice to start with Pythagorean triples.)

Let $a, b, c, d$ be positive integers satisfying
$$ \tag{$1$}
\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} - \frac{1}{d^2} \, .
$$
By replacing $(a, b, c, d)$ with $(c, d, a, b)$ or $(a, c, b, d)$, if necessary, we can assume that $a \le b \le c \le d$, and actually $a < b \le c < d$ since we want to exclude the “trivial solutions.” By dividing all numbers by $\gcd(a, b, c, d)$ we can also assume that $a, b, c, d$ have no factor in common.

I'll call $(a, b, c, d)$ a “primitive solution” of $(1)$ if $a < b \le c < d$ and $\gcd(a, b, c, d) = 1$.

Now let $(a, b, c, d)$ be a primitive solution of $(1)$ and let $l = \operatorname{lcm}(a, b, c, d) $ be their least common multiple. Then
$$
 (x, y, z, t) = \left( \frac la, \frac lb,\frac lc,\frac ld\right)
$$
is a quadruple of positive integers satisfying
$$ \tag{$2$}
x^2-y^2 = z^2-t^2 \, .
$$
It is also not difficult to see that $x > y \ge z > t$ and $\gcd(x, y, z, t) = 1$. I'll call that a “primitive solution” of $(2)$.

So a primitive solution of $(1)$ leads to a primitive solution of $(2)$.

But the converse is also true: If $(x, y, z, t)$ is a primitive solution of $(2)$ and $L = \operatorname{lcm}(x, y, z, t) $ their least common multiple then
$$
 (a, b, c, d) = \left( \frac Lx, \frac Ly,\frac Lz,\frac Lt\right)
$$
is a primitive solution of $(1)$.

Therefore it suffices to determine all primitive solutions of $(2)$. Writing that equation in the form
$$ \tag{$*$}
 x^2 + t^2 = y^2 + z^2 
$$
shows that this task amounts to find positive integers which can be represented in two (or more) ways as the sum of two squares. The smallest integer with this property is $N=50$, compare https://oeis.org/A007692.

*Example:* $50 = 1^2+7^2 = 5^2+5^2$, so $(x, y, z, t) = (7, 5, 5, 1)$ is a primitive solution of $(2)$ with least common multiple $L=35$. This gives the solution
$$
 \frac{1}{5^2} - \frac{1}{7^2} = \frac{1}{7^2} - \frac{1}{35^2} \, .
$$

So a recipe to compute all primitive solutions of $(1)$ could look like this:

- Enumerate the positive integers $N$ which can be represented as the sum of two squares. The [Sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) can help to find these numbers efficiently.
- For each such number $N$, determine all pairs $(u_i, v_i)$ of non-zero integers such that $u_i^2+v_i^2 = N$.
- If there are at least two such pairs, try all combinations  $(u_i, u_j, v_j, v_i)$ with $i \ne j$.
- If $u_i > u_j \ge v_j > v_i$ and $\gcd(u_i, u_j, v_j, v_i) = 1$ then
  $$
   (a, b, c, d) = \left( \frac L{u_i}, \frac L{u_j},\frac L{v_j},\frac L{u_i}\right)
  $$
  with $L = \operatorname{lcm}(u_i, u_j, v_j, v_i)$ is a primitive solution of $(1)$.

Comment: in 1910, Welsch stated that all solutions of $u^2 + x^2 = y^2 + z^2$  are $2x= ab+cd, \; \; $ $ 2y=ac+bd , \;\;$  $2z= ab-cd, \;\; $ $2u=ac-bd . \; \; $ Page 254 in Dickson's History, Volume II.   Here all four of $abcd$  are odd, or two are ven.  The usual lemma is  when $pq=rs,$  take $g = \gcd(p,r)  $ and   continue, the outcome is $p=g \alpha, \; \; $ $q=h \gamma, \; \; $   $ r = g \beta, \; \; $  $s = h \delta . \; \;$

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks! I am sure that this can be improved/simplified considerably. Unfortunately, I do not have that book (or other literature on elementary number theory). Therefore I have only sketched the rough idea. – When I find the time I will try to look it up!

Comment: Martin, my little program is in  pretty good shape, posted in answer. It produces all of your $x^2 - y^2 = z^2 - t^2$  up to a bound I called maxtarget, each line begun with that value of $x^2 + t^2$ I piped to a grep command to show all   the $(x,y,z,t)$  quadruples for a certain target

Comment: @WillJagy: “in pretty good shape” does not apply to *formatting* of the program, does it? – Just kidding. Thanks for that, I will play with your program later (apparently I have to install GMP first).

Comment: Right. They let me audit a C++  class about 1995, so that is what I use for my own programs. My impression is that Python is fairly natural  for number theory, may allow large integers. Anyway, I write things that are easier to remember than the original C style commands, for example mpz_class mp_Sqrt( mpz_class  w)
{
  if (w <= 0) return 0;
  else if (w < 2) return 1;
  else
  {
    mpz_class squirt;
    mpz_sqrt( squirt.get_mpz_t(), w.get_mpz_t()  );
    return  squirt ;
  }  // else w >= 2;
}

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I  had left out some important inequalities on my variables $p,q,r,s$  in solving Martin's $x^2 - y^2 = z^2 - t^2$  with  $ y \geq z.$   I put in a number called `maxtarget' that bounds everything. Here is output, restricted to ( the command grep)  to $x^2 + t^2 = 32045=5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 29.$  Quite fast.  The only surprising condition would be that at least one of $p,q$  is required odd. If both are even, we get a duplicate quadruple by changing $(p,q,r,s)$  to $(p/2,q/2, 2r,2s)$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse | sort -n
        50        p: 3 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 7 y: 5 z: 5 t: 1
        65        p: 5 q: 1 r: 3 s: 1           x: 8 y: 7 z: 4 t: 1
        85        p: 4 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 9 y: 7 z: 6 t: 2
       125        p: 7 q: 1 r: 3 s: 1           x: 11 y: 10 z: 5 t: 2
       130        p: 5 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 11 y: 9 z: 7 t: 3
       145        p: 3 q: 1 r: 7 s: 3           x: 12 y: 9 z: 8 t: 1
       170        p: 4 q: 1 r: 6 s: 2           x: 13 y: 11 z: 7 t: 1
       185        p: 6 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 13 y: 11 z: 8 t: 4
       205        p: 9 q: 1 r: 3 s: 1           x: 14 y: 13 z: 6 t: 3
       221        p: 5 q: 1 r: 5 s: 3           x: 14 y: 11 z: 10 t: 5
       250        p: 7 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 15 y: 13 z: 9 t: 5
       265        p: 7 q: 2 r: 4 s: 2           x: 16 y: 12 z: 11 t: 3
       290        p: 3 q: 1 r: 10 s: 4           x: 17 y: 13 z: 11 t: 1
       305        p: 11 q: 1 r: 3 s: 1           x: 17 y: 16 z: 7 t: 4
       325        p: 11 q: 3 r: 3 s: 1           x: 18 y: 15 z: 10 t: 1
       325        p: 7 q: 1 r: 5 s: 1           x: 18 y: 17 z: 6 t: 1
       325        p: 8 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 17 y: 15 z: 10 t: 6
       338        p: 5 q: 1 r: 6 s: 4           x: 17 y: 13 z: 13 t: 7
       365        p: 3 q: 1 r: 11 s: 5           x: 19 y: 14 z: 13 t: 2
       370        p: 6 q: 1 r: 6 s: 2           x: 19 y: 17 z: 9 t: 3
       377        p: 5 q: 1 r: 7 s: 3           x: 19 y: 16 z: 11 t: 4
       410        p: 9 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 19 y: 17 z: 11 t: 7
       425        p: 13 q: 1 r: 3 s: 1           x: 20 y: 19 z: 8 t: 5
       425        p: 7 q: 1 r: 5 s: 3           x: 19 y: 16 z: 13 t: 8
       425        p: 9 q: 2 r: 4 s: 2           x: 20 y: 16 z: 13 t: 5
       442        p: 5 q: 1 r: 8 s: 2           x: 21 y: 19 z: 9 t: 1
       445        p: 13 q: 3 r: 3 s: 1           x: 21 y: 18 z: 11 t: 2
       481        p: 6 q: 1 r: 6 s: 4           x: 20 y: 16 z: 15 t: 9
       485        p: 3 q: 1 r: 13 s: 5           x: 22 y: 17 z: 14 t: 1
       493        p: 4 q: 1 r: 10 s: 4           x: 22 y: 18 z: 13 t: 3
       505        p: 10 q: 1 r: 4 s: 2           x: 21 y: 19 z: 12 t: 8
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ date
Wed Feb  2 14:25:20 PST 2022
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse | grep "  32045 "
     32045        p: 3 q: 1 r: 103 s: 47           x: 178 y: 131 z: 122 t: 19
     32045        p: 3 q: 1 r: 107 s: 37           x: 179 y: 142 z: 109 t: 2
     32045        p: 4 q: 1 r: 76 s: 42           x: 173 y: 131 z: 122 t: 46
     32045        p: 4 q: 1 r: 84 s: 22           x: 179 y: 157 z: 86 t: 2
     32045        p: 5 q: 1 r: 63 s: 31           x: 173 y: 142 z: 109 t: 46
     32045        p: 5 q: 1 r: 67 s: 21           x: 178 y: 157 z: 86 t: 19
     32045        p: 8 q: 1 r: 36 s: 26           x: 157 y: 131 z: 122 t: 86
     32045        p: 8 q: 1 r: 44 s: 6           x: 179 y: 173 z: 46 t: 2
     32045        p: 12 q: 1 r: 28 s: 10           x: 173 y: 163 z: 74 t: 46
     32045        p: 13 q: 1 r: 23 s: 15           x: 157 y: 142 z: 109 t: 86
     32045        p: 13 q: 1 r: 27 s: 5           x: 178 y: 173 z: 46 t: 19
     32045        p: 17 q: 1 r: 19 s: 9           x: 166 y: 157 z: 86 t: 67
     32045        p: 19 q: 4 r: 18 s: 4           x: 179 y: 163 z: 74 t: 2
     32045        p: 21 q: 1 r: 13 s: 11           x: 142 y: 131 z: 122 t: 109
     32045        p: 21 q: 1 r: 17 s: 1           x: 179 y: 178 z: 19 t: 2
     32045        p: 22 q: 3 r: 14 s: 8           x: 166 y: 142 z: 109 t: 67
     32045        p: 27 q: 5 r: 11 s: 7           x: 166 y: 131 z: 122 t: 67
     32045        p: 31 q: 5 r: 11 s: 3           x: 178 y: 163 z: 74 t: 19
     32045        p: 31 q: 12 r: 10 s: 4           x: 179 y: 131 z: 122 t: 2
     32045        p: 32 q: 9 r: 10 s: 4           x: 178 y: 142 z: 109 t: 19
     32045        p: 33 q: 4 r: 10 s: 4           x: 173 y: 157 z: 86 t: 46
     32045        p: 43 q: 6 r: 8 s: 2           x: 178 y: 166 z: 67 t: 19
     32045        p: 47 q: 1 r: 7 s: 3           x: 166 y: 163 z: 74 t: 67
     32045        p: 49 q: 8 r: 6 s: 4           x: 163 y: 131 z: 122 t: 74
     32045        p: 61 q: 7 r: 5 s: 3           x: 163 y: 142 z: 109 t: 74
     32045        p: 69 q: 13 r: 5 s: 1           x: 179 y: 166 z: 67 t: 2
     32045        p: 80 q: 3 r: 4 s: 2           x: 163 y: 157 z: 86 t: 74
     32045        p: 113 q: 7 r: 3 s: 1           x: 173 y: 166 z: 67 t: 46
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ date
Wed Feb  2 14:25:26 PST 2022
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
int main()
{

mpz_class   x,y,p,q,r,s,n,z,w,nn,t;
mpz_class  a,b,c,d, bound, maxtarget;


maxtarget = 32045;

bound = 1+ mp_Sqrt( 2 * maxtarget);

for(p = 1; p <= bound; ++p){
for(q=1; q < p; ++q){
for(r=1; r <= bound  &&  p*r*p*r <= 4*maxtarget  &&  q*r*q*r <= 4*maxtarget; ++r){
for(s=1; s < r    &&  (p*s  + q*r)*(p*s  + q*r)  <= 4*maxtarget  && (p*r + q*s)*(p*r + q*s) <= 4*maxtarget; ++s){


if ( (p*r+q*s)  % 2 == 0 && (p*r-q*s) > 0 && (p*s+q*r)  % 2 == 0 && (p*s-q*r) > 0 &&  mp_coprime4(p,q,r,s)   ) {

   x = (p*r + q*s)/2;
   y = (p*r - q*s)/2;
     z = (p*s + q*r)/2;
     t = (p*s - q*r)/2;
  if( mp_coprime4(x,y,z,t) &&  x > z  && y >= z &&  (p % 2 == 1 || q % 2 ==1   ) )  {
  cout << setw(10) << x *x + t*t ;
 cout << "        p: " << p << " q: " << q << " r: " << r << " s: " << s;
 cout << "           x: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << " t: " << t << endl;
} // if xyzt
} // if  




}}}}


  return 0;
}
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
   1185665        p: 4 q: 1 r: 462 s: 256           x: 1052 y: 796 z: 743 t: 281
   1185665        p: 4 q: 1 r: 482 s: 216           x: 1072 y: 856 z: 673 t: 191
   1185665        p: 4 q: 1 r: 498 s: 176           x: 1084 y: 908 z: 601 t: 103
   1185665        p: 4 q: 1 r: 504 s: 158           x: 1087 y: 929 z: 568 t: 64
   1185665        p: 5 q: 1 r: 381 s: 193           x: 1049 y: 856 z: 673 t: 292
   1185665        p: 5 q: 1 r: 383 s: 189           x: 1052 y: 863 z: 664 t: 281
   1185665        p: 5 q: 1 r: 401 s: 147           x: 1076 y: 929 z: 568 t: 167
   1185665        p: 5 q: 1 r: 409 s: 123           x: 1084 y: 961 z: 512 t: 103
   1185665        p: 6 q: 1 r: 314 s: 172           x: 1028 y: 856 z: 673 t: 359
   1185665        p: 6 q: 1 r: 326 s: 148           x: 1052 y: 904 z: 607 t: 281
   1185665        p: 6 q: 1 r: 332 s: 134           x: 1063 y: 929 z: 568 t: 236
   1185665        p: 6 q: 1 r: 346 s: 92           x: 1084 y: 992 z: 449 t: 103
   1185665        p: 8 q: 1 r: 242 s: 120           x: 1028 y: 908 z: 601 t: 359
   1185665        p: 8 q: 1 r: 258 s: 80           x: 1072 y: 992 z: 449 t: 191
   1185665        p: 9 q: 2 r: 214 s: 100           x: 1063 y: 863 z: 664 t: 236
   1185665        p: 9 q: 2 r: 220 s: 86           x: 1076 y: 904 z: 607 t: 167
   1185665        p: 11 q: 3 r: 169 s: 89           x: 1063 y: 796 z: 743 t: 236
   1185665        p: 11 q: 3 r: 181 s: 61           x: 1087 y: 904 z: 607 t: 64
   1185665        p: 12 q: 1 r: 142 s: 112           x: 908 y: 796 z: 743 t: 601
   1185665        p: 12 q: 1 r: 152 s: 98           x: 961 y: 863 z: 664 t: 512
   1185665        p: 12 q: 1 r: 158 s: 88           x: 992 y: 904 z: 607 t: 449
   1185665        p: 12 q: 1 r: 178 s: 32           x: 1084 y: 1052 z: 281 t: 103
   1185665        p: 13 q: 1 r: 153 s: 67           x: 1028 y: 961 z: 512 t: 359
   1185665        p: 13 q: 1 r: 157 s: 57           x: 1049 y: 992 z: 449 t: 292
   1185665        p: 13 q: 4 r: 144 s: 70           x: 1076 y: 796 z: 743 t: 167
   1185665        p: 13 q: 4 r: 150 s: 56           x: 1087 y: 863 z: 664 t: 64
   1185665        p: 17 q: 1 r: 105 s: 73           x: 929 y: 856 z: 673 t: 568
   1185665        p: 17 q: 1 r: 123 s: 35           x: 1063 y: 1028 z: 359 t: 236
   1185665        p: 17 q: 1 r: 125 s: 27           x: 1076 y: 1049 z: 292 t: 167
   1185665        p: 17 q: 1 r: 127 s: 15           x: 1087 y: 1072 z: 191 t: 64
   1185665        p: 19 q: 3 r: 103 s: 47           x: 1049 y: 908 z: 601 t: 292
   1185665        p: 19 q: 3 r: 107 s: 37           x: 1072 y: 961 z: 512 t: 191
   1185665        p: 19 q: 4 r: 96 s: 58           x: 1028 y: 796 z: 743 t: 359
   1185665        p: 19 q: 4 r: 104 s: 42           x: 1072 y: 904 z: 607 t: 191
   1185665        p: 21 q: 1 r: 79 s: 67           x: 863 y: 796 z: 743 t: 664
   1185665        p: 21 q: 1 r: 89 s: 53           x: 961 y: 908 z: 601 t: 512
   1185665        p: 21 q: 1 r: 101 s: 23           x: 1072 y: 1049 z: 292 t: 191
   1185665        p: 21 q: 1 r: 103 s: 11           x: 1087 y: 1076 z: 167 t: 64
   1185665        p: 22 q: 3 r: 92 s: 34           x: 1063 y: 961 z: 512 t: 236
   1185665        p: 22 q: 3 r: 94 s: 28           x: 1076 y: 992 z: 449 t: 167
   1185665        p: 25 q: 2 r: 68 s: 54           x: 904 y: 796 z: 743 t: 607
   1185665        p: 25 q: 2 r: 76 s: 42           x: 992 y: 908 z: 601 t: 449
   1185665        p: 25 q: 2 r: 84 s: 22           x: 1072 y: 1028 z: 359 t: 191
   1185665        p: 25 q: 2 r: 86 s: 12           x: 1087 y: 1063 z: 236 t: 64
   1185665        p: 27 q: 5 r: 73 s: 31           x: 1063 y: 908 z: 601 t: 236
   1185665        p: 27 q: 5 r: 77 s: 19           x: 1087 y: 992 z: 449 t: 64
   1185665        p: 31 q: 1 r: 57 s: 41           x: 904 y: 863 z: 664 t: 607
   1185665        p: 31 q: 1 r: 63 s: 31           x: 992 y: 961 z: 512 t: 449
   1185665        p: 31 q: 1 r: 67 s: 21           x: 1049 y: 1028 z: 359 t: 292
   1185665        p: 31 q: 1 r: 69 s: 13           x: 1076 y: 1063 z: 236 t: 167
   1185665        p: 31 q: 5 r: 61 s: 33           x: 1028 y: 863 z: 664 t: 359
   1185665        p: 31 q: 5 r: 63 s: 29           x: 1049 y: 904 z: 607 t: 292
   1185665        p: 32 q: 7 r: 62 s: 24           x: 1076 y: 908 z: 601 t: 167
   1185665        p: 32 q: 7 r: 64 s: 18           x: 1087 y: 961 z: 512 t: 64
   1185665        p: 33 q: 4 r: 56 s: 34           x: 992 y: 856 z: 673 t: 449
   1185665        p: 33 q: 4 r: 64 s: 14           x: 1084 y: 1028 z: 359 t: 103
   1185665        p: 42 q: 11 r: 46 s: 20           x: 1076 y: 856 z: 673 t: 167
   1185665        p: 43 q: 6 r: 46 s: 20           x: 1049 y: 929 z: 568 t: 292
   1185665        p: 45 q: 11 r: 41 s: 23           x: 1049 y: 796 z: 743 t: 292
   1185665        p: 45 q: 11 r: 43 s: 19           x: 1072 y: 863 z: 664 t: 191
   1185665        p: 47 q: 1 r: 39 s: 25           x: 929 y: 904 z: 607 t: 568
   1185665        p: 47 q: 1 r: 45 s: 11           x: 1063 y: 1052 z: 281 t: 236
   1185665        p: 47 q: 16 r: 40 s: 18           x: 1084 y: 796 z: 743 t: 103
   1185665        p: 49 q: 2 r: 36 s: 26           x: 908 y: 856 z: 673 t: 601
   1185665        p: 49 q: 2 r: 44 s: 6           x: 1084 y: 1072 z: 191 t: 103
   1185665        p: 49 q: 8 r: 40 s: 18           x: 1052 y: 908 z: 601 t: 281
   1185665        p: 56 q: 3 r: 32 s: 22           x: 929 y: 863 z: 664 t: 568
   1185665        p: 56 q: 3 r: 38 s: 8           x: 1076 y: 1052 z: 281 t: 167
   1185665        p: 59 q: 17 r: 33 s: 13           x: 1084 y: 863 z: 664 t: 103
   1185665        p: 61 q: 7 r: 33 s: 13           x: 1052 y: 961 z: 512 t: 281
   1185665        p: 67 q: 21 r: 29 s: 11           x: 1087 y: 856 z: 673 t: 64
   1185665        p: 69 q: 7 r: 25 s: 19           x: 929 y: 796 z: 743 t: 568
   1185665        p: 69 q: 7 r: 31 s: 5           x: 1087 y: 1052 z: 281 t: 64
   1185665        p: 69 q: 13 r: 29 s: 11           x: 1072 y: 929 z: 568 t: 191
   1185665        p: 71 q: 18 r: 28 s: 10           x: 1084 y: 904 z: 607 t: 103
   1185665        p: 73 q: 6 r: 28 s: 10           x: 1052 y: 992 z: 449 t: 281
   1185665        p: 79 q: 7 r: 23 s: 15           x: 961 y: 856 z: 673 t: 512
   1185665        p: 79 q: 7 r: 27 s: 5           x: 1084 y: 1049 z: 292 t: 103
   1185665        p: 80 q: 3 r: 22 s: 16           x: 904 y: 856 z: 673 t: 607
   1185665        p: 80 q: 3 r: 26 s: 8           x: 1052 y: 1028 z: 359 t: 281
   1185665        p: 101 q: 23 r: 19 s: 9           x: 1063 y: 856 z: 673 t: 236
   1185665        p: 103 q: 11 r: 19 s: 9           x: 1028 y: 929 z: 568 t: 359
   1185665        p: 113 q: 7 r: 17 s: 9           x: 992 y: 929 z: 568 t: 449
   1185665        p: 113 q: 7 r: 19 s: 3           x: 1084 y: 1063 z: 236 t: 103
   1185665        p: 118 q: 5 r: 14 s: 12           x: 856 y: 796 z: 743 t: 673
   1185665        p: 118 q: 5 r: 18 s: 4           x: 1072 y: 1052 z: 281 t: 191
   1185665        p: 135 q: 4 r: 14 s: 8           x: 961 y: 929 z: 568 t: 512
   1185665        p: 135 q: 4 r: 16 s: 2           x: 1084 y: 1076 z: 167 t: 103
   1185665        p: 167 q: 3 r: 11 s: 7           x: 929 y: 908 z: 601 t: 568
   1185665        p: 167 q: 3 r: 13 s: 1           x: 1087 y: 1084 z: 103 t: 64
   1185665        p: 178 q: 19 r: 12 s: 2           x: 1087 y: 1049 z: 292 t: 64
   1185665        p: 179 q: 2 r: 12 s: 2           x: 1076 y: 1072 z: 191 t: 167
   1185665        p: 191 q: 1 r: 9 s: 7           x: 863 y: 856 z: 673 t: 664
   1185665        p: 191 q: 1 r: 11 s: 3           x: 1052 y: 1049 z: 292 t: 281
   1185665        p: 194 q: 57 r: 10 s: 4           x: 1084 y: 856 z: 673 t: 103
   1185665        p: 198 q: 41 r: 10 s: 4           x: 1072 y: 908 z: 601 t: 191
   1185665        p: 201 q: 22 r: 10 s: 4           x: 1049 y: 961 z: 512 t: 292
   1185665        p: 202 q: 9 r: 10 s: 4           x: 1028 y: 992 z: 449 t: 359
   1185665        p: 251 q: 33 r: 7 s: 5           x: 961 y: 796 z: 743 t: 512
   1185665        p: 253 q: 9 r: 7 s: 5           x: 908 y: 863 z: 664 t: 601
   1185665        p: 263 q: 24 r: 8 s: 2           x: 1076 y: 1028 z: 359 t: 167
   1185665        p: 264 q: 7 r: 8 s: 2           x: 1063 y: 1049 z: 292 t: 236
   1185665        p: 269 q: 97 r: 7 s: 3           x: 1087 y: 796 z: 743 t: 64
   1185665        p: 277 q: 71 r: 7 s: 3           x: 1076 y: 863 z: 664 t: 167
   1185665        p: 281 q: 53 r: 7 s: 3           x: 1063 y: 904 z: 607 t: 236
   1185665        p: 283 q: 41 r: 7 s: 3           x: 1052 y: 929 z: 568 t: 281
   1185665        p: 298 q: 49 r: 6 s: 4           x: 992 y: 796 z: 743 t: 449
   1185665        p: 302 q: 1 r: 6 s: 4           x: 908 y: 904 z: 607 t: 601
   1185665        p: 371 q: 43 r: 5 s: 3           x: 992 y: 863 z: 664 t: 449
   1185665        p: 373 q: 19 r: 5 s: 3           x: 961 y: 904 z: 607 t: 512
   1185665        p: 423 q: 59 r: 5 s: 1           x: 1087 y: 1028 z: 359 t: 64
   1185665        p: 427 q: 9 r: 5 s: 1           x: 1072 y: 1063 z: 236 t: 191
   1185665        p: 467 q: 138 r: 4 s: 2           x: 1072 y: 796 z: 743 t: 191
   1185665        p: 477 q: 98 r: 4 s: 2           x: 1052 y: 856 z: 673 t: 281
   1185665        p: 478 q: 93 r: 4 s: 2           x: 1049 y: 863 z: 664 t: 292
   1185665        p: 483 q: 62 r: 4 s: 2           x: 1028 y: 904 z: 607 t: 359
   1185665        p: 665 q: 179 r: 3 s: 1           x: 1087 y: 908 z: 601 t: 64
   1185665        p: 671 q: 155 r: 3 s: 1           x: 1084 y: 929 z: 568 t: 103
   1185665        p: 679 q: 115 r: 3 s: 1           x: 1076 y: 961 z: 512 t: 167
   1185665        p: 685 q: 71 r: 3 s: 1           x: 1063 y: 992 z: 449 t: 236
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Answer (score 0):

There are various variants of such equations. For example like this.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h2465588_a_class_of_diophantine_equations_in_three_variables

When solving such equations.
$$\frac{ 1 }{ a^2 } -\frac{ 1 }{ b^2 } = \frac{ 1 }{ c^2 } - \frac{ 1 }{ d^2 } $$

Pythagorean triples can help us. Take any two Pythagorean triples.
$$\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&  p^2=s^2+n^2   \\
&  k^2=t^2+j^2  
\end{aligned}\right.  $$

Then the solutions can be written in this form. Then the truth needs to be reduced by a common divisor.

$a=ktsn$

$b=pstj$

$c=ktpn$

$d=pskj$

Comment: Yandex translates. Therefore, I try to write fewer words.

Comment: Ok. The last sentence does not make sense. That's why I asked.

Comment: It makes sense. There it is necessary to obtain mutually simple solutions. They are obtained by dividing by a common divisor. Then they will understand themselves when they will make calculations.

Comment: I understand your solution. But the word choice in the last sentence is unclear (for me). Anyway, don't mind it : )

Answer (score 0):

we take, $(a,b,c,d)=(pq,rq,st,wt)$

where, $r^2=p^2+q^2$ & $w^2=s^2+t^2$

And, $(r,p,q)=((u^2+v^2),(u^2-v^2),(2uv))$

$(w,s,t)=((m^2+n^2),(m^2-n^2),(2mn))$

We have Identity,

$(1/rp)^2=(1/pq)^2-(1/rq)^2$  ---(1)

$(1/ws)^2=(1/st)^2-(1/wt)^2$  ----(2)

we want, eqn (1)=eqn (2)

Hence, $pr=sw$

or

$(u^4-v^4)=(m^4-n^4)$ ----(3)

eqn (3) has numerical solution:

$(m,n,u,v)=(59,134,133,158)$

hence,

$(p,q,r)=(7275,42028,42653)$

$(s,t,w)=(14475,15812,21437)$

$a=305753700$

$b=1792620284$

$c=228878700$

$d=338961844$